# How to make this work? - android programming

Tags: java, android

I want this code-part to set an onclick listener on each button (I've already made these buttons in another method) and when they are clicked it saves (to a file) its "number" or id. I know how to save text, but when i try to save the "l" variable it saves its last value and not the value when it's created. I can't think of any other solutions.

```
    for(final int l[]={0}; l[0] < filea.length; l[0]++ )
    {
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(l[0]);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                //
                //save method here
            }
        });
```

Comment: That is definitely not how findViewById works at all.

Comment: I know I write crappy code, I'm still learning. But thanks for the reply I will rethink all "parts" where I used this.

Comment: This makes me think that you're setting the ID of the button yourself. Is this true?

Comment: I thought I can't do anything with the button unless I "find" it with findviewbyid.

Comment: So I'll try to include as much information as I can here for you but you're likely doing this whole thing wrong... If you're programmatically adding these buttons into your layout (they are not in the layout xml file already, you're using `addView`) then you should be keeping a list of Button objects that you can easily reference like this `myButtonList.get(l)`. If you have buttons in the layout, you should be using `android:id="@+id/my_example_id"` and then do this: `findViewById(R.id.my_example_id)`. (You can change `my_example_id` to anything you want but they have to match)

Comment: In your specific case, I can't help you too much without seeing more of what you're doing here. If you were able to post the entire class on Pastebin.com and link me I could provide you more constructive help

Comment: @iismathwizard Hello I've already added the buttons to a layout in a similar loop with addview. But thanks for the reply now I know that findviewbyid is if I used when a view is made in the layout xml file.

Comment: In that case, just keep a list of the buttons objects in your activity and refer to that list instead of `findViewById` and you'll be good.

Comment: Okey, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the final variable inside the loop body:

```
for ( int ll = 0; ll < filea.length; ++ll )
{
   final int l = ll;   // Use this in the listener.

   // Rest of loop body.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your loop construction is a bit weird (why not use a variable l that you loop through rather than the l array construct - if you want to use the total just use filea.length outside of the loop).

By the time your callback is invoked the array's value in index 0 is already at the maximum. Use button.getId() inside the loop instead.

Comment: Don't promote bad habits in android by suggesting that `getId` is an okay solution.

Comment: I've been trying to find a solution by myself and tried out everything. I realised it was a stupid idea but I forgot to remove it from the code when I uploaded it.

Comment: @iismathwizard what's your beef with getId() - terse much?

Comment: @NilsMeier an id in android is not something that you should assign yourself unless you're using one of android's ID generating methods. The android operating system should be the one to assign the id as it will guarantee that each id is unique. The best solution is to hold an array or list of the buttons and reference them through that list (which using a for loop, this is quite easy to do)

Comment: @NilsMeier by using getId to get the "index" of a button is only promoting this bad design since it implies that the id's are iterated from  0..`filea.length`

Comment: @iismathwizard I wasn't suggesting to assign an id - thus getter getId() - it's actual very normal to use IDs in views, there's official API for it, you get views by ID, etc. That's not a bad habit at all FYI

Comment: @NilsMeier additionally, it's silly not to keep a list/array of button objects when OP's obviously just trying to find a convenient way to refer to them by *index*. I'm not sure why that wasn't proposed as a solution.